# Cake NuGetPack Configuration

Tags: nuget-package, cakebuild

I'm trying to create a NuGet package using a Cake script:

```
var configuration = Argument("configuration", "Release");

var binDir = Directory("./bin") ;
var nugetPackageDir = Directory("./artifacts");

var nugetFilePaths = GetFiles("./**/*.csproj").Concat(GetFiles("./**/*.nuspec"));

var nuGetPackSettings = new NuGetPackSettings
{   
  BasePath = binDir + Directory(configuration),
  OutputDirectory = nugetPackageDir  
};

Task("NuGetPack")
  .Does(() => NuGetPack(nugetFilePaths, nuGetPackSettings));
```

I get the following error:

```
========================================
NuGetPack
========================================
Executing task: NuGetPack
Attempting to build package from 'SomeProject.csproj'.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '12.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin'.
Unable to find 'C:\DEV\SomeProject\bin\Debug\SomeProject.dll'. Make sure the project has been built.
An error occured when executing task 'NuGetPack'.
Error: NuGet: Process returned an error (exit code 1).
```

It searches the assembly in the `Debug` folder instead of the `Release` folder.
How to set NuGetPack build configuration to Release in Cake?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the following command line argument `-Prop Configuration=Release` to the `nuget pack` command:

```
var nuGetPackSettings = new NuGetPackSettings
{   
  BasePath = binDir + Directory(configuration),
  OutputDirectory = nugetPackageDir,
  ArgumentCustomization = args => args.Append("-Prop Configuration=" + configuration)
};
```

Answer (score 8):

It can be set using the `Properties` property:

```
var nuGetPackSettings = new NuGetPackSettings
{
  BasePath = binDir + Directory(configuration),
  OutputDirectory = nugetPackageDir,
  Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
    { "Configuration", configuration }
  }
};
```